# parse array in charts js laravel blade

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, charts

I need show temperature monthly to charts in laravel 
my view page consist 
temp.blade

```
<script>
    console.log({!! $temp !!});
    console.log({!! $dateTemp !!});
    window.onload = function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: {!! $temp !!},
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Temperature',
                data: {!! $dateTemp !!},
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        }
    });
    }
</script>
```

and controller

```
public function tempChart()
{
    $temp = Temps::select(DB::raw('temp'))
        ->orderBy('date_temp','asc')
        ->get();
    $temp->implode(',',$temp);
    $dateTemp = Temps::select(DB::raw('temps'))
        ->select('date_temp')
        ->orderBy('date_temp','asc')
        ->get();
    $dateTemp->implode(',',$dateTemp);
    //dd($temp,$dateTemp);
    return view('report/temp')
        ->with('temp',$temp)
        ->with('dateTemp',$dateTemp);
}
```

it can not show data array but it show

> [{...}],[{...}],[{...}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure which Chart library you are using but most of them wants an array of strings or integer and you give them array of objects.

I think that you just need to convert your array in the php (or in the javescript)

php way:

```
$temp = Temps::select('temp'`)
    ->orderBy('date_temp','asc')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('temp');


$dateTemp = Temps::select(['temps', 'data-temp'])
    ->orderBy('date_temp','asc')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('data-temp'); // I am not whats the acual query you want but this is the idea
```

and then if you using laravel 5.5 just write on your blade

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: @json($temp),
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Temperature',
                data: @json($dateTemp) ,
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        }
    });

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add high comma to Data?

```
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Temperature',
            data: '{!! $dateTemp !!}',
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
```

Comment: No , error Uncaught TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object

Comment: array:3 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▶]
  1 => array:1 [▶]
  2 => array:1 [▶]
]
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▶]
  1 => array:1 [▶]
  2 => array:1 [▶]
]

Comment: what is about json_encode on the array? not implode

Comment: I use both toarray and implode the same results.